# Delete an element in Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, element, delete-operator

I have an Arrays (size=5) like this

`int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};`

How I can delete 4 and than finally (size=4) like this

`int[] arr = {1,2,3,5}`

Comment: You can't change the length of an array in Java.  You can either create a new array of a smaller size and copy the elements over, or use a `List`.

Comment: Short response: you cannot. Long resonse: you can, but you need to create a new array. Correct response: Please show us what you have done so far and ask specific question, so we can explain to you the concepts that you do not understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way is to make a new array of size 4 and copy the elements you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a list of modifiable size I recommend an ArrayList. It has a remove function and the size is dyanamic.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
arrlist.remove(4);//will remove the 4th index and the size will decrease by 1
```

With an ArrayList you can add, remove, sort, and do many other functions that can be read about here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html